# Example google app engine (python, Django) websites with open source

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine

I am learning to create a website using google app engine with python and django. Does anyone have sample websites with open source that i can look at and learn from ?

thanks,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A nice variety of example projects:

http://code.google.com/p/google-app-engine-samples/

Comment: Thanks @Calvin, I am looking at what @Flow gave. I will also be looking at the link that you have given.

Comment: Tweaking these samples is how I got my bearings in App Engine.  Using "Add Existing Application" from Google's App Engine Launcher you can have these running on dev_appserver in minutes.

Answer (score 2):

Checkout [rietveld](http://code.google.com/p/rietveld/), a code review web app along with its [source code](http://code.google.com/p/rietveld/source/browse/#svn/trunk).